# Bash substring last occurance of a character

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to write a script that removes everything after the last occurrence of a character. For example if the string is `DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24`, I would like to get just `DATETIME 2014.03.`. So everything after the last occurrence of a dot should be stripped. I've been trying different variants with `sed` and `expr index` but without success. The last time I tried to get the index of the last dot and then substring it but without any result:

`expr index "DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24" '.[0-9][/&][0-9]'`

This returns the position of the first dot instead of the last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parameter expansion. `%` deletes the final portion of a string

```
 d='DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24'
 echo ${d%.*}.
```

Output:

```
DATETIME 2014.03.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I demonstrate a way to solve it with `sed`:

```
$ echo "DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24" | sed 's/[^.]*$//'
DATETIME 2014.03.
```

- `[^.]*$` matches anything *but* a literal dot, 0 or more times, followed by the end of the line.

Note that this will remove all characters from strings that do not contain the delimiter. If this is not wanted, a version that "anchors" the substitution to the delimiter could be:

```
$ echo "DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$/./'
DATETIME 2014.03.
```

- `\.` matches a literal dot.
- The last occurence of `.` reinserts the delimiter character that would otherwise be removed. A variant without this extra repetition could be:

  ```
  $ echo "DATETIME 2014.03.14 12:23:24" | sed 's/\(\.\)[^.]*$/\1/'
  DATETIME 2014.03.
  ```

  where the delimiter is captured to not have to reenter it explicitly in the substitution pattern.